How to define a titleclass to have an auto-incrementing counter and/or set the counter in the document?
I'm trying to get the added title class of subdoc to increment its counter or set its counter.
In the preamble, it can be set; but in the document I can't get it to change with \setcounter or \stepcounter.
Also, the \titlecontent styling/formatting works only for the numberless-entry-format.
Thus, I must be overlooking something fundamental and obvious. Would you please tell me what that is?
I'm trying to get the second occurrence of "Book One" to be "Book Two."
Thank you.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[newparttoc,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleclass\subdoc{straight}[\part]
\newcounter{subdoc}
\setcounter{subdoc}{1}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\huge\vspace*{\fill}}
{PART\nobreakspace\thepart.\vspace{15pt}\\
\rule[0.5ex]{0.35\textwidth}{1.2pt}\\%
\vspace{-10pt}
}
{0mm}
{}
[\vspace*{\fill}]

\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]
{\centering\large\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{}{\pagebreak\vspace*{15pt}}}
{\parbox[t][3ex][t]{\linewidth}{\em\centering\partname~%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{First}{Second}.}\\\scshape}
{}
{\vspace{10pt}\\\centering\rule[0.5ex]{0.25\textwidth}{1pt}}
[\vspace{20pt}]

\titlecontents{subdoc}[0pt]
{}
{}
{\parbox[t][3ex][t]{\linewidth}{\scshape\bfseries\centering\ Book~%
\ifthenelse{\value{subdoc}=1}{One}{Two}.}\\%
\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1.5pt}\\\scshape}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\textsf{\footnotesize\contentspage}}
[\vspace{2ex}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{subdoc}{Subdoc 1}
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}

\setcounter{subdoc}{2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subdoc}{Subdoc 2}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}

\end{document}


